# Is there a way of viewing a function's source code using the Dis module in Python?

Tags: python, module, reversing

If, for example, I want to view the bytecode for the function x:

```
def f(x):
    print(x * 10)
```

I would use the `dis` module, which would generate this:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     print(x * 10)
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Yet, is there a way to view the actual code of the function? For example, the output would be:

```
def func1(var1):
    const1 = 10
    print(var1 * const1)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to get from arbitrary bytecode back  to human readable code?

Comment: @timgeb yes, that's correct.

Comment: Seems like it is a duplicate. Thank you!